# Delete last row of each group after using GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am looking for a solution for deleting the last row of each group after using GroupBy.

DataFrame `Farmers` is filled with the working progress of several farmers who send information in a certain time intervall (minutes). The Index of this dF is  `FarmerName`.

```
Criteria = pd.DataFrame()
Criteria['HourList'] = farmers.groupby(['FarmerName','date','hour'])['hour'].unique()
Criteria
```

With `Criteria` I want to display the hours a farmer is active on a certain day.

```
FarmerName  date            hour     'HourList'
George      2019-04-01      6        [6]
                            7        [7]
                            8        [8]
                            9        [9]
                            10       [10]
Albert      2019-04-01      12       [12]
                            13       [13]
                            14       [14]
                            15       [15]
                            16       [16]
```

The end result should look like this:

```
FarmerName  date            hour     'HourList'
George      2019-04-01      6        [6]
                            7        [7]
                            8        [8]
                            9        [9]

Albert      2019-04-01      12       [12]
                            13       [13]
                            14       [14]
                            15       [15]
```

Trying to slice `Criteria` with `Criteria[:-1]` is a wrong approach (it just slices `hour 16` of Farmer `Albert`). I have tried around with `.apply()` but none of the attempts worked out.

Is there an easy solution to this issue?

Comment: You're close. `ddf = df.groupby([...]).apply(lambda x : x[:-1])`

Comment: Why are you doing unique? It's a group level so it's guaranteed to be identical to that level, just as a list with the single element.

Comment: `u = Criteria.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(ascending=False); Criteria[u > 0]`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are really trying to accomplish? This seems a like you've started to go down the wrong path to solve your underlying issue. If your problem is to remove the `last hour` within each Farmer and Date, grouping is unnecessary.

Comment: @Valentino : Yep this is what I tried at first. Ended up with the same result as `Criteria[:-1]`.

Comment: @ALollz Because I need the hour values in order to do further calculations. It looks weird, I know.